# NEW to SQL - incorrect syntax at WHERE

Tags: sql-server, subquery, min

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT 
     APUI.APCo, APUI.UIMth, APUI.UISeq, APUI.Vendor, APUI.APRef, 
     APUI.InvDate, APUL.Line, APUL.LineType, APUL.Description, 
     APUL.GrossAmt, APUL.Job, APUR.Reviewer, APUL.GLAcct, 
     APUR.ApprvdYN, APUR.Rejected, 
     HQRV.Name, JCJM.Description AS Expr1, APVM.Name AS VenName, 
     APVM.Phone, APUL.MiscAmt, APUR.LoginName, APVM.SortName, 
     APVM.Vendor AS VenID, APUL.Units, APUL.UnitCost, APUL.UM, 
     HQMT.Description AS MAtDescr, APUL.GLCo, 
     APUL.MiscYN, APUI.Notes, APUL.Discount, APUL.SMCostType, 
     APUR.ApprovalSeq, 
     CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM, 
     CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM2
FROM            
    dbo.APUI AS APUI 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APUL AS APUL ON APUI.APCo = APUL.APCo 
                        AND APUI.UIMth = APUL.UIMth 
                        AND APUI.UISeq = APUL.UISeq 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APVM AS APVM ON APUI.VendorGroup = APVM.VendorGroup 
                        AND APUI.Vendor = APVM.Vendor 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APUR AS APUR ON APUL.APCo = APUR.APCo 
                        AND APUL.UIMth = APUR.UIMth 
                        AND APUL.UISeq = APUR.UISeq 
                        AND APUL.Line = APUR.Line 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.JCJM AS JCJM ON APUL.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo 
                        AND APUL.Job = JCJM.Job 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.HQMT AS HQMT ON APUL.MatlGroup = HQMT.MatlGroup  
                        AND APUL.Material = HQMT.Material 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.HQRV AS HQRV ON APUR.Reviewer = HQRV.Reviewer
GROUP BY 
    APUI.APCo, APUI.UIMth, APUI.UISeq, APUI.Vendor, APUI.APRef, 
    APUI.InvDate, APUL.Line, APUL.LineType, APUL.Description, 
    APUL.GrossAmt, APUL.Job, APUR.Reviewer, APUL.GLAcct, APUR.ApprvdYN, 
    APUR.Rejected, HQRV.Name, JCJM.Description, APVM.Name, APVM.Phone, 
    APUL.MiscAmt, APUR.LoginName, APVM.SortName, APVM.Vendor, APUL.Units, 
    APUL.UnitCost, APUL.UM, HQMT.Description, APUL.GLCo, APUL.MiscYN, 
    APUI.Notes, APUL.Discount, APUL.SMCostType, APUR.ApprovalSeq, 
    CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4))
 WHERE 
     ApprovalSeq = (SELECT MIN(ApprovalSeq) AS hasball
                    FROM dbo.XS_Unapproved_Inv_Current_Approver 
                    WHERE (MATCHNUM = MATCHNUM2))
```

[I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuSp8.jpg)

I am trying to return the min number for each group in the field `'MatchNum'`

I have been working on this for HOURS please help before I go insane!

Here is a screenshot of the results. I am trying to just return the record in red

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enXSp.jpg)

Comment: `WHERE` goes before `GROUP BY`

Comment: That's correct, that's the only fix to your query

Comment: You have both distinct AND group by. You don't need both. And you also do not need TOP when you also have 100 percent.

Comment: Another challenge after formatting this is you are aliasing your tables but the alias is the same as the actual table name. That kind of defeats the purpose. I also noticed you have the exact same derived column twice (MATCHNUM and MATCHNUM2). Why do you need the same thing in 2 columns?

Comment: Your question edit reveals to me that you tried to post your SQL code as a code block, but didn't manage to. For your information: if you want to submit code on stackoverflow in a code block you need to insert 4 spaces before ALL lines that need to be interpreted as code. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Welcome on SO!

Comment: I moved the where before the group by and now I have this error Msg 147, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Please copy the error text into the question, instead of linking to screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a syntactically valid query based on the one you posted. I don't understand the point of your derived MatchNum and MatchNum2 at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT APUI.APCo
    , APUI.UIMth
    , APUI.UISeq
    , APUI.Vendor
    , APUI.APRef
    , APUI.InvDate
    , APUL.Line
    , APUL.LineType
    , APUL.Description
    , APUL.GrossAmt
    , APUL.Job
    , APUR.Reviewer
    , APUL.GLAcct
    , APUR.ApprvdYN
    , APUR.Rejected
    , HQRV.Name
    , JCJM.Description AS Expr1
    , APVM.Name AS VenName
    , APVM.Phone
    , APUL.MiscAmt
    , APUR.LoginName
    , APVM.SortName
    , APVM.Vendor AS VenID
    , APUL.Units
    , APUL.UnitCost
    , APUL.UM
    , HQMT.Description AS MAtDescr
    , APUL.GLCo
    , APUL.MiscYN
    , APUI.Notes
    , APUL.Discount
    , APUL.SMCostType
    , APUR.ApprovalSeq
    , Cast(APUI.APCo AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.UISeq AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.Vendor AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUL.GrossAmt AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM
    --, Cast(APUI.APCo AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.UISeq AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.Vendor AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUL.GrossAmt AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM2
FROM   dbo.APUI AS APUI
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APUL AS APUL ON APUI.APCo = APUL.APCo
                                   AND APUI.UIMth = APUL.UIMth
                                   AND APUI.UISeq = APUL.UISeq
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APVM AS APVM ON APUI.VendorGroup = APVM.VendorGroup
                                   AND APUI.Vendor = APVM.Vendor
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APUR AS APUR ON APUL.APCo = APUR.APCo
                                   AND APUL.UIMth = APUR.UIMth
                                   AND APUL.UISeq = APUR.UISeq
                                   AND APUL.Line = APUR.Line
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JCJM AS JCJM ON APUL.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo
                                   AND APUL.Job = JCJM.Job
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HQMT AS HQMT ON APUL.MatlGroup = HQMT.MatlGroup
                                   AND APUL.Material = HQMT.Material
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HQRV AS HQRV ON APUR.Reviewer = HQRV.Reviewer
WHERE ApprovalSeq = 
    (
        SELECT  min(ApprovalSeq)
        From dbo.XS_Unapproved_Inv_Current_Approver 
        --Where MATCHNUM = MATCHNUM2 Why bother checking this? Those values can't possibly ever not be equal, they are derived from the same expression
    )
```

--EDIT--

It still is not at all clear what you are really trying to do here. This is my last shot in the dark. When posting you need to post the desired output. I have absolutely no idea what defines a "group" in your data so you may have to adjust the PARTITION BY clause of the ROW_NUMBER window function. If I understand correctly this should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

```
with SortedValues as
    (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY APUI.APCo order by APUR.ApprovalSeq) as RowNum
        , APUI.APCo
        , APUI.UIMth
        , APUI.UISeq
        , APUI.Vendor
        , APUI.APRef
        , APUI.InvDate
        , APUL.Line
        , APUL.LineType
        , APUL.Description
        , APUL.GrossAmt
        , APUL.Job
        , APUR.Reviewer
        , APUL.GLAcct
        , APUR.ApprvdYN
        , APUR.Rejected
        , HQRV.Name
        , JCJM.Description AS Expr1
        , APVM.Name AS VenName
        , APVM.Phone
        , APUL.MiscAmt
        , APUR.LoginName
        , APVM.SortName
        , APVM.Vendor AS VenID
        , APUL.Units
        , APUL.UnitCost
        , APUL.UM
        , HQMT.Description AS MAtDescr
        , APUL.GLCo
        , APUL.MiscYN
        , APUI.Notes
        , APUL.Discount
        , APUL.SMCostType
        , APUR.ApprovalSeq
        , Cast(APUI.APCo AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.UISeq AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUI.Vendor AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) + Cast(APUL.GrossAmt AS DECIMAL(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM
    FROM   dbo.APUI AS APUI
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APUL AS APUL ON APUI.APCo = APUL.APCo
                                       AND APUI.UIMth = APUL.UIMth
                                       AND APUI.UISeq = APUL.UISeq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APVM AS APVM ON APUI.VendorGroup = APVM.VendorGroup
                                       AND APUI.Vendor = APVM.Vendor
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.APUR AS APUR ON APUL.APCo = APUR.APCo
                                       AND APUL.UIMth = APUR.UIMth
                                       AND APUL.UISeq = APUR.UISeq
                                       AND APUL.Line = APUR.Line
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JCJM AS JCJM ON APUL.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo
                                       AND APUL.Job = JCJM.Job
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HQMT AS HQMT ON APUL.MatlGroup = HQMT.MatlGroup
                                       AND APUL.Material = HQMT.Material
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.HQRV AS HQRV ON APUR.Reviewer = HQRV.Reviewer
)

select *
from SortedValues
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: IF you look at the pic I just posted it might make some help. I am sure that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Not sure what that image is supposed to demonstrate. You are missing some business rules in your explanation.

Comment: Let me try to explain a little better  i'm trying to return only one record for each group that record should be the minimum number of the approvseq. The reason for the number and number two was to create a matching group I may not need that to get the results I'm looking for

Comment: @Steve see my edit. It would help if you explained what a group is in your data.

Comment: Sean, it did point me in the right direction!! Thank you very much. Next time I will make the post much clearer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you need a closing parenthesis ) at the end of your statement:

```
WHERE ApprovalSeq = (
      SELECT  min(ApprovalSeq) AS hasball
      From dbo.XS_Unapproved_Inv_Current_Approver 
      Where (MATCHNUM = MATCHNUM2)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I did close the statement but I am still getting Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 1):

move the group by down the WHERE clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TOP (100) PERCENT APUI.APCo, APUI.UIMth, APUI.UISeq, APUI.Vendor, APUI.APRef, APUI.InvDate, APUL.Line, APUL.LineType, APUL.Description, APUL.GrossAmt, 
    APUL.Job, APUR.Reviewer, APUL.GLAcct, APUR.ApprvdYN, APUR.Rejected, HQRV.Name, JCJM.Description AS Expr1, APVM.Name AS VenName, APVM.Phone, 
    APUL.MiscAmt, APUR.LoginName, APVM.SortName, APVM.Vendor AS VenID, APUL.Units, APUL.UnitCost, APUL.UM, HQMT.Description AS MAtDescr, APUL.GLCo, 
    APUL.MiscYN, APUI.Notes, APUL.Discount, APUL.SMCostType, APUR.ApprovalSeq , CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 
    4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM, CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) 
    + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4)) AS MATCHNUM2
FROM            
    dbo.APUI AS APUI LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APUL AS APUL ON APUI.APCo = APUL.APCo AND APUI.UIMth = APUL.UIMth AND APUI.UISeq = APUL.UISeq LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APVM AS APVM ON APUI.VendorGroup = APVM.VendorGroup AND APUI.Vendor = APVM.Vendor LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.APUR AS APUR ON APUL.APCo = APUR.APCo AND APUL.UIMth = APUR.UIMth AND APUL.UISeq = APUR.UISeq AND APUL.Line = APUR.Line LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.JCJM AS JCJM ON APUL.JCCo = JCJM.JCCo AND APUL.Job = JCJM.Job LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.HQMT AS HQMT ON APUL.MatlGroup = HQMT.MatlGroup AND APUL.Material = HQMT.Material LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.HQRV AS HQRV ON APUR.Reviewer = HQRV.Reviewer




WHERE ApprovalSeq = 
(
SELECT  min(ApprovalSeq) AS hasball
From dbo.XS_Unapproved_Inv_Current_Approver 
Where (MATCHNUM = MATCHNUM2))

GROUP BY APUI.APCo, APUI.UIMth, APUI.UISeq, APUI.Vendor, APUI.APRef, APUI.InvDate, APUL.Line, APUL.LineType, APUL.Description, APUL.GrossAmt, APUL.Job, 
APUR.Reviewer, APUL.GLAcct, APUR.ApprvdYN, APUR.Rejected, HQRV.Name, JCJM.Description, APVM.Name, APVM.Phone, APUL.MiscAmt, APUR.LoginName, 
APVM.SortName, APVM.Vendor, APUL.Units, APUL.UnitCost, APUL.UM, HQMT.Description, APUL.GLCo, APUL.MiscYN, APUI.Notes, APUL.Discount, 
APUL.SMCostType, APUR.ApprovalSeq, CAST(APUI.APCo AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.UISeq AS decimal(10, 4)) + CAST(APUI.Vendor AS decimal(10, 4)) 
+ CAST(APUL.GrossAmt AS decimal(10, 4))
```

Comment: correct, I missed that one. Simple rule to remember the order a statement: SELECT JOIN WHERE GROUP HAVING